# jQuery ,Css display none - block vs. hide- show

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hide, display

I am trying to hide #showMyList, #showMyName these divs. On click button need to show divs.
Both div has separate buttons. I want to see one div at a time. I can give different css (style)to them so that they will look different.

Which one will be more useful jQuery hide() and show() 
Or display none and block?

```
#showMyList, #showMyName{
            height: 100px;
            width: 500px;
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid gray;
            background-color: antiquewhite;
            position: absolute;
            top: 200px;
            left:200px;
        }
    </style> 
    <script>
        $('document').ready(function(){
           $('showMyList').css("display", "none");
            $('showMyAcc').css("display","none");
            $("myList").click(function(){
                $("showMyList").css("display", "block");
                $("myAcc").click(function(){
                  $("showMyAcc").css("display", "block");  
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: `hide()` and `show()` is preferable to using `css()`. `addClass()` and `removeClass()` are also better practice than using `css()`

Comment: Both `.css()` and `.hide()` / `.show()` simple add to the elements style attribute. So there would be no issue in setting up the CSS initially and then using JS to show one or the other. The issue I see here is that there is a `click` event nested inside another click event.

Comment: You also have severe selector issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#showMyList, #showMyAcc').hide();
  $("#myList").click(function() {
    $("#showMyAcc").hide();
    $("#showMyList").show();
  });
  $("#myAcc").click(function() {
    $("#showMyList").hide();
    $("#showMyAcc").show();
  });
});
```

```css
#showMyList,
#showMyAcc {
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myList">Show List</button>
<button id="myAcc">Show Name</button>
<div id="showMyList">List</div>
<div id="showMyAcc">Name</div>
```

You can Hide both elements and then reveal or show 1 at a time.